# UserForm Object with Methods in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create an Object representing a UserForm, with methods to add Controls, and a method to present the UserForm.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around object-oriented VBA, and the tutorials/answers/documentation aren't helping me.

Here's how I imagine the Object and an example of its methods.

```
Sub UI_Window(caption as String)

    Dim Form As Object

    '   This is to stop screen flashing while creating form
    Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False

    Set Form = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)

    With Form
        .Properties("Caption") = caption
        .Properties("Width") = 600
        .Properties("Height") = 50
    End With

    return Form

    Sub addButton(action as String, code as String)
    
        Set NewButton = Form.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
        With NewButton
            .Name = "cmd_1"
            .Caption = action
            .Accelerator = "M"
            .Top = Form.Height
            .Left = 50
            .Width = 500
            .Height = 100
            .Font.Size = 14
            .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
            .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
        End With

        '   Adjust height of Form to added content
        With Form
            .Properties("Height") = Form.Height + NewButton.Height + 50
        End With

        '   Should loop through code argument, line-by-line
        Form.codemodule.insertlines 8, "Private Sub cmd_1_Click()"
        Form.codemodule.insertlines 9, "msgbox (""Button clicked!"")"
        Form.codemodule.insertlines 10, "End Sub"
    
    End Sub

    Sub present()

        'Show the form
        VBA.UserForms.Add(Form.Name).Show
    
        'Delete the form
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove Form
    
    End Sub

End Sub
```

And here's how it would be used

```
Sub SampleWindow()

    Set Window = UI_Window "Window Title"
    Window.addButton "Click me", "msgbox (""Button clicked!"")"
    Window.present()

End Sub
```

Comment: Your "UI_Window" would be implemented as a [Class](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx) which would hold within itself a refentce to the new user form.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check out this guide

Comment: I can't find the logic in the class declaration/initialisation. The Type declaration/initialisation makes total sense. Can I just use a Type but add methods rather than properties?

Answer (score 1):

Please, try this adapted way:

1. Copy the next code on top of module where the following code exists:

```
   Public frm As Object 'to use it even after the UserForm has been created
                        'to avoid it deletion when tested the code
```

2. Copy the next code in the same standard module:

```
Sub CreateAFormWithAButton()
 Const formName As String = "MyNewForm"
 Const formCaption As String = "My Form"
 
 removeForm formName 'remove the previously created form, if the case

 UI_Window formCaption, formName            'create the new form

 addButton frm, "myFirstButton", "Click Me" 'add a button
 VBA.UserForms.Add(frm.Name).Show           'show the newly created form
End Sub

Function formExists(frmName As String) As Boolean
   Dim fr As Variant
   For Each fr In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
       If fr.Type = vbext_ct_MSForm Then
            If frmName = fr.Name Then
                Set frm = fr
                formExists = True: Exit Function
            End If
       End If
   Next
End Function

Sub UI_Window(frmCaption As String, frmName As String)

    Set frm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm) '3

    With frm
        .Properties("Caption") = frmCaption
        .Properties("Width") = 500
        .Properties("Height") = 200
        .Properties("Name") = frmName
    End With
End Sub

Sub addButton(form As Object, btName As String, btCaption As String)
    Dim NewButton As MSForms.CommandButton
        If buttonExists(btName) Then MsgBox "A button named """ & btName & """ already exists...": Exit Sub 
        Set NewButton = form.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
        With NewButton
            .Name = btName
            .caption = btCaption
            .top = 0
            .left = 50
            .width = 100
            .height = 40
            .Font.size = 14
            .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        End With

        '   Should loop through code argument, line-by-line
        form.CodeModule.InsertLines 8, "Private Sub " & btName & "_Click()"
        form.CodeModule.InsertLines 9, "     msgbox (""Button clicked!"")"
        form.CodeModule.InsertLines 10, "End Sub"
End Sub

Function buttonExists(btName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ctrl As Variant
    For Each ctrl In frm.Designer.Controls
        If ctrl.Name = btName Then buttonExists = True: Exit Function
    Next
End Function

Sub removeForm(frmName As String)
 Dim i As Long, strName As String
 If Not formExists(frmName) Then Exit Sub

 strName = "TestName"
tryAgain:
 On Error Resume Next
  frm.Name = strName
  If err.Number = 75 Then                 'a previously used name...
     err.Clear                            'clear the error
        strName = strName & i: i = i + 1  'increment the new string
        frm.Name = strName: GoTo tryAgain 'test the new name again
  End If
 On Error GoTo 0
 ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove frm
End Sub
```

If you will try running the code for the second time, you cannot create a button with the same name. The code check if the name exists and warn. It can be adapted to propose another name (adding an incremented number), but it needs also to set other positioning, making the code more complicated and this does not make the object of the question, I would say...

Please, run/test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you specify where the "Public frm As Object" should be inserted? What does the final Macro look like?

Comment: @ThorLindberg You should place it on top of the module where the whole code will stay/exist. In the declarations area... In fact, if you will use a new module, start by copying the `Public` declaration and then the rest of the code (Subs/Functions)...

Comment: Thank you! I made the following new Macro (StackOverflow.bas), which gets assigned as StackOverflow.CreateAFormWithAButton. Unfortunately it returns Run-time error '440': Method 'Add' of object '_VBComponents' failed. https://gist.github.com/thorlindberg/0e337f51f1a46fbf1cac78caee0cf56d

Comment: @ThorLindberg On which line such an error is raised? The above code creates a form, names it "MyNewForm", add a button on it, writes its click event and shows the newly created form. Did you run it once, then deleted the form and tried again the code, using the same form name?

Comment: It's raised on line 28, "Set frm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm) '3".

Comment: @ThorLindberg Was that happening when you firstly tried the code? Please, look to the existing forms. Can't you see a new form named "MyNewForm"?

Comment: Yes, it happens when I first run the code. And no UserForm is created

Comment: @ThorLindberg I cannot understand what's happening in your installation... Do you have `AnyDesk` installed? If so, can I remotely connect to your computer and see where the problem is? What Excel version do you use?

Comment: The error is caused by "vbext_ct_MSForm" in "Set frm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)". If I change it to "Set frm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)" then the UserForm is created. Could you change your answer so the UserForm is just overwritten if it already exists, and is deleted after it's closed? I'll accept it then :)

Comment: @ThorLindberg In order to recognize that constant, please add a reference to `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibilty 5.3`. If it looks complicated, even if it is not, I can place a piece of code doing it programmatically. It is not possible to "overwrite" a `UserForm`. That's why I tried splitting the code in a way to allow using the created one. Besides that, even if you will manually delete the newly created `UserForm` and try running the code using **the same form name**, VBA will not accept **that name**... It remains somewhere in the workbook properties as an existing form.

Comment: @ThorLindberg I experimented a little and I found a way to remove the created form, in a way to make VBA accepting the same name. It is needed to previously change its name. But, the new changed name will behave the same when try renaming... In order to go out from this vicious circle I have in mind a loop incrementing a prefix to be added when renaming. Not having too much availability now, but I will adapt the above code to allow using the same `UserForm` name. A kind of overwriting, but not exactly. It means the form name changing and then removing it.

Comment: @ThorLindberg Please, test the updated solution and send some feedback. It will work as you required in your last comment.